Finding a matching with a specific weight
Polynomial-time algorithms for finding a maximum-weight matching in a weighted graph are well-known. Suppose I want not the maximum-weight matching, but a matching with a specific weight given as an input (that is smaller than the maximum). I can probably find such a matching using linear programming, but are there any known combinatorial polynomial-time algorithms for that?
I am interested mainly in bipartite graphs.

It is not hard to see, that the problem is weakly-NP hard by using a reduction to SUBSET-SUM:
Given an instance $p_1, p_2, ... p_n$ and a target sum $T$ and construct a bipartite graph consisting of vertices $V = \{v_0, v_0', v_1, v_1', ... v_n, v_n'\}$ and construct for each $p_i$ an edge $(v_i, v_i')$ with weight $p_i$.
It is easy to see that a matching of weight $T$ exsist if and only if a subset of size $T$ exists.
But I don't know if the problem is NP-hard in the strong sense or if a pseudopolynomial algorithm exist but is suspect the former (maybe a 3-PARTITION reduction could work).

Using Tutte matrix, there exists a randomized, weakly-polynomial $O(n^{\omega} W)$ time algorithm for the problem, where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication exponent, and $W$ is the maximum matching weight.
